# Objective-C and Swift ABI

Tags: objective-c, swift

I know there are still some ABI (Application Binary Interface) issues between different versions of Swift, and it can cause a framework built with one version of Swift to not usable by an application built with another version of Swift.

But I am not sure if Objective-C and Swift have such an issue. That is to say, can a framework built with Swift be consumed by any version of Objective-C, in the ABI context?